# Can Gatling execute more than one Karate scenario from a feature file?

Tags: performance-testing, karate

I am using Karate-Gatling combo to test backend. I have one test where I would like to

1. Update some info about account
2. Upload multiple files (one by one)
3. Save changes

Simplest way to simulate this would be to have `Scenario` for the 1. and 3. step, and have `Scenario Outline` for step 2. with all the different files in `Examples:`. All in the same `.feature` file.

However when I run this with Gatling, only the first scenario in the list gets executed. Is there a way to make Gatling run the others as well?  I suppose that there could be a trick with dynamic outlines, but I'm asking if I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to execute them in sequence or in parallel? Remember scenarios are supposed to run in parallel.
Could you provide extracts of the source code?

Also, would be good to know the Karate version, considering the recent 1.0 release.

Answer (score 0):

All the `Scenario`-s in the feature-file should be executed. Please check if maybe the first `Scenario` is exiting with an error.

Otherwise this is a bug. Please then follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue